# non-class type error with SDL_Rect

Tags: sdl, sdl2

I am building a pong game in SDL2 as my first assignment for my game development class. I've encountered an error involving `SDL_Rect` that I can't figure out. I am using `SDL_Rect`s in conjunction with `SDL_HasIntersection(const SDL_Rect * A,const SDL_Rect * B)` to detect collisions, and I have the collide method in the actor superclass from which all actors (pong ball, paddles, etc) inherit. Here is my code for actor.cpp:

```
#include "actor.h"

/**
SUPERCLASS

 Each actor has
-position (2D vector)
-speed and direction (2D vector)
-bounding box (SDL_Rect)
-strings to define file path for texture (needed when drawing window)

Each child of actor must implement
-setBoundingBox (will be different for each actor)

Each actor can implement
-collide(const &actor)

**/

actor::actor(void)
{
    imageFilePath = "";

    SDL_Rect rect;

    boundingBox = rect;

    vec2D placeholder(0.0f, 0.0f);

    directionVelocity = placeholder;

    position = placeholder;

}

SDL_Rect actor::setBoundingBox() //must be overwritten, sets bounding box
{
    SDL_Rect placeholder;
    placeholder.w = 0;
    placeholder.w = 0;
    return placeholder;
}

bool actor::collide(const &actor) const //checks if an actor is colliding with another 
actor
{
    if (SDL_HasIntersection(&boundingBox, &actor.boundingBox))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

vec2D actor::getPosition() //gets actor's current position
{
    return position;
}

vec2D actor::getDirectionVelocity() //gets the actor's current direction and velocity
{
    return directionVelocity;
}

void actor::updatePosition(vec2D newPos) //updates both the actor's bounding box and 
position using a new position vector (intended for ball and paddles)
{
    boundingBox.x = newPos.u;
    boundingBox.y = newPos.v;
    position = newPos;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
error: request for member 'boundingBox' in 'actor', which is of non-class type 'const 
int'
46 |     if (SDL_HasIntersection(&boundingBox, &actor.boundingBox))
```

I'm not sure how to get around this. Could it be because the actor's `boundingBox` member in the constructor is set to an incomplete `SDL_Rect`? That `SDL_Rect rect` is just a placeholder, and I have a virtual `setBoundingBox()` function in my actor.h file that each subclass must override. The actor class itself is never instantiated in my main function, just subclasses of it.

Comment: It sounds like somehow actor::collide is getting called with an argument that's an integer instead of an actor. Is it possible in your collision-testing loop you've accidentally passed the index of the item instead of the item at that index in the collection?

Comment: The collide function's argument list looks a bit weird to me, or maybe I'm missing something. Is the `&actor` argument the data type or the actor passed in?
Shouldn't it be `bool actor::collide(const actor& theOtherActor)`?